# Pressure loss of for flushing sand filter with air

Tags: fluid-mechanics, process-engineering

This is a cut-away view of a sand filter:

[image]

For flushing the filter, water and then air is pumped/blown under the filter. I'm interested in the pressure loss:

- The lower bound for the required air pressure is the water level above the nozzles
- in systems with about 2m sand and a total of 3 m water, how much will be approximately the influence of the sand layer? (assume typical filter speeds (air flow / surface area) of around 90 m/h)
- How does the pressure loss change over time during flushing, if at all

The numbers are indicative. I'm mostly looking for a feel for the pressure loss.